# Render to texture a moving object in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i set up a render to texture material and a cam.  I want the cam to capture a 3d die rolling and render that capture to a raw image in a screen space canvas. The problem is that it seems to capture all of the die movements. Here is a screenshot.
[image]

There seems to be some strange trailing going on. Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you able to show your code?

Comment: There is no code involved and I answered my own question. Like always it's mostly my own stupidity that causes the problems :D

Comment: Glad you resolved it in any case.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I duplicated my background camera that was set to depth only and that was causing the problem. If you want to capture moving object with Render to texture use solid color on the cam's CLear Flags